# Best way to bind crab cakes

Tags: crab

What is the best way to bind crab cakes? I cannot, ever, use any kind of flour or breadcrumbs, no even NG flour/bread; no bread, cracker, flour G or NG.

Would just an egg or egg white be enough to bind the crab cake?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Why do you say "clearly no bread crumbs"?

Comment: The questions states 'the waiter told me the chef adds almost nothing ... no fillers' @FuzzyChef, that implies no breadcrumbs.

Comment: "almost nothing" is quite different from "nothing".  For example, I personally add a little flour to my crab cakes to help them hold together.  1/2 cup of breadcrumbs is a filler; 1 Tbs is a binder.

Comment: But what about an egg? or at least the white?  I really do not mind dropping the crumbs, but not sure I can drop the egg or white.  What are your thoughts on the egg?

Comment: So your question is "what are the minimum binders required to hold a crab cake together"?   If that's correct, can you edit your original question to clarify?

Comment: If you search for ‘gluten free Maryland crab cakes’, you should find some recipes that don’t use breadcrumbs.  (There are people who insist that breadcrumbs shouldn’t be used in ‘true’ Maryland crab cakes.). But you’ll also find a lot of recipes that call for gluten free breadcrumbs

Answer (score 3):

It probably depends on how you’re planning on cooking your crab cakes.

There’s a style of Maryland crab cakes that are baked or broiled (top heat only) in an oven that don’t require as much binder as you don’t need to flip them or need them to hold together in a fryer.

For this style, it might be bound with just egg, or a mix of egg and mayonnaise.

Here are some example recipes:

- [using egg, egg yolk and mayo](https://feelslikehomeblog.com/maryland-crab-cakes-with-no-filler-low-carb-bariatric-friendly-recipe/)
- [using just mayonnaise](https://theeverykitchen.com/easy-no-filler-crab-cakes/)